# Relationship form view to viewmodel

Tags: c#-4.0

I am new to MVVM pattern. I got a view on which I painted several controls, a treeview, a list, a combobox, a datepicker, and a progressbar. I will name this view as PFORM1

Should I have only one viewmodel class for this PFORM1 view or should I have several viewmodel classes, each corresponding to one control on the view?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There would be one ViewModel per View. Not per control.
The ViewModel would expose properties for binding to the control's properties.